# Javascript async function that calls and waits for google auth

Tags: javascript, async-await, google-authentication

If I replace the asynch/await below with a then(gAuth) construct my call to Google Auth Init works. At present the init() call never returns and the browser hangs.

Am I misunderstanding the requirements of "await"?

```
async function gInit() {
  // Check if already logged in with Google
  try {
    gAuth = await gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: providers.google.clientId
    })
    alert("sign in: " + gAuth.isSignedIn.get());
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err.message || err.text)
    delete providers.google;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is probably an issue with `gapi.auth2.init` returning a promise that resolves with itself, thus creating an endless resolution loop. See https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/268

Comment: Ah, sounds reasonable. I'll go back to .then() Thanks

Comment: @Phil What do you mean by "resolves with itself"?

Comment: @guest271314 `init` returns a `GoogleAuth` object. This object has a `then` method making it pass `is-promise`. The `then` method resolves with the `GoogleAuth` object itself so you can easily create an endless, recursive promise resolution loop. See the linked issue in my first comment

Comment: ... though it appears they've recently changed the API but not in any way that makes OP's code possible. The `then` method now resolves with the return value of its first, `onInit` argument. Not entirely clear what it does if that is omitted

Comment: @Phil Interesting. What pattern do the authors of the code suggest to use? Is the pattern in compliance with `Promises/A+` specification? One example at linked issue uses `Promise.resolve()` and `.then()`; what are the means to prevent the unexpected result?

Comment: @guest271314 Looks like I need to re-read the documentation but all my current code is littered with global calls to `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()`. The real problem is trying to write any promise-based code that you'd like to resolve with the `GoogleAuth` object. It's just not possible because of its stupid `then` method

Comment: @Phil Have you viewed any responses from the authors of the code to the issues filed?

Comment: @Phil Is this the official response _"Warning: do not use this method alongside the recommended gapi.auth2.init and signIn flow. These are two distinct behaviors (Authorization for gapi.auth2.authorize vs Authentication for gapi.auth2.init/signIn) and will have unexpected issues if used within the same application."_ https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauththenoninit? Essentially "won't fix"?

Comment: @guest271314 no, I believe that's something else. The comments from Google in that issue no longer apply as they've changed the API. Probably the best workaround is to wrap the `GoogleAuth` in another object as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/268#issuecomment-274565410)